# How to use python regex to extract first part of the context

Tags: python, regex

```
string='there is a article here, there will be some other article too'
```

String is the content, I want `'there is a article'`, and stop there, don't match to the article at the end.

I used `there.+article`, but it gives me the full content `'there is a article here, there will be some other article`. No I don't want this.

There is what I desire:
`'there is a article'`

Comment: Do you always need to extract the part before the comma?

Comment: no, this is only an very simple example. real case is much longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *lazy quantifier* as follows:

`there.+?article`

This will match all `there ... article` presences in the input sentence.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1Aab8/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` to match non-greedily.

```
>>> string='there is a article here, there will be some other article too'
>>> import re
>>> re.match("there.+article", string)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 57), match='there is a article here, there will be some other>
>>> re.match("there.+?article", string)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='there is a article'>
```

Comment: Thank you, CinCout responded slightly quicker than you did, I'll accept CinCout's answer. But thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you wish to design this expression:

```
^.+?\barticle\b
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^.+?\barticle\b"
test_str = "there is a article here, there will be some other article too"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['there is a article']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFFy6v/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]